# MKMapView rendering problem on iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, ios, mapkit, mkmapview

My problem occurs only on iPad. There is always unrendered portion of MKMapView(right side on the picture below). As soon as I touch this window the mapview repaints itself just fine. But it never renders correctly right away. This problem occures in iOS 4.2 as well as in iOS 3.2 in Simulator and the Device.   The code that constructs MKMapView is right below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];  
      mapview = [[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,230)] autorelease]; // because of apples bug
      mapview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
      MKCoordinateSpan globe = MKCoordinateSpanMake(100, 100);

      CLLocationCoordinate2D worldCenter; worldCenter.latitude = 42.032974; worldCenter.longitude =21.359375;

      MKCoordinateRegion worldmap = MKCoordinateRegionMake(worldCenter, globe);
      mapview.region = worldmap;
      mapview.zoomEnabled = NO;
      mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
      mapview.delegate = self;

      NSRange theRange;
      theRange.location = 1;
      theRange.length = [annotations count]-1;

      [mapview addAnnotations:[annotations subarrayWithRange:theRange]];
      [self.view addSubview:mapview];   
}
```

**The problem  manifests itself only in Landscape orientation.**

[image: Incorrect span]
UPDATE

This is how it spans after I touched the view. 
[image: Correct span]

Comment: looks like you're trying to center the map in the world center with a span that is too large for the map to fill the whole screen? As far as I can see there's no map 'left' on the right hand side of the screen for it to render - i.e. that's the end of the world :) - so try playing with the span values to see if it fix your problem.

Comment: @Rog As soon as I touch this view it renders just fine. It always has enough world view because it auto-scales by clipping altitude of the globe.

Comment: Cool what do you see on the right hand side when you touch the screen and it re-renders? I just tried my max zoom out on the Maps app and the right hand side coincides with what you have posted above so I'm curious!?

Comment: @Rog I added the second screenshot.

Comment: @Rog I'll try to play with center and span tonight. I am just thinking since our planet is round the center point can't be really off. Span can be, but it should compensated by auto-zooming itself.

Comment: @Rog. You were right. Want to post your last comment in answers section?

Comment: I just used this and solved issue on iPhone mapview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

Comment: What I found was that when the mapview is bigger than the window bounds, it fails to render properly... maybe the autoresizeFlexibleWidth extended the frame of the mapview beyond the window width...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick test with your code and get the same result (which I expected). I still think it is not an issue with the map itself but with the way you are setting your center coordinates plus map span. You're trying to center the map too far to the left with max span and the only way for the map to fill the entire screen and maintain the center point would be for it to stretch itself, which is not desirable. If you set lat and long to 0 you get the same view without the missing part.

Answer (score 1):

Nonetheless it's Apple's bug. In iPad-landscape mode your longtitude span may not be enough to cover 360degree of the globe. it should autoscale with zoom, but it doesn't. it autozooms properly only if your centerMap is exactly at 0 degree longitude. Weird.

**Workaround:**

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D worldCenter; worldCenter.latitude = 42.032974; 
    worldCenter.longitude = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)? 0.0 : 21.359375;
    mapview.centerCoordinate = worldCenter;
}
```